# How to create a loop that run the code from beginning

Tags: c#, loops

How to loop back the code to the first line after it done the calculation?

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Temp in Celcius");
int x = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
if (x <= -271.15)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Temperature below absolute zero!");
    }
else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is " + ((x * 1.8) + 32) + "F");
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-do-statement

Comment: a `while` loop will do what you want

Answer (score 0):

If its a continous loop thats required, use a `while` or `do while` loop and exit based on user input. The `do while` version executes the code atleast once and then executes further till the condition turns false and `while` version executes only when condition is met and conntinues to execute till the condition turns false

```
bool continueProcessing = true;
while (continueProcessing) --condition
{
Console.WriteLine("Enter Temp in Celcius");
int x = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
if (x <= -271.15)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Temperature below absolute zero!");
    }
else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is " + ((x * 1.8) + 32) + "F");
    }
}
```

Now inside the loop, get the user input and check if he wants to continue and set the value of `continueProcessing` to false. Try to implement that part yourself and see :)